# CSS nested div:hover does not work

Tags: html, css

Intention:

- a div with a pretty picture and title
- when the visitor hovers over the div, the pretty stuff is replaced by a descriptive text
- a CSS-only solution

simple, right?

Here's what I am trying:

HTML:

```
<div class="drunter">
    I am below
    <div class="drueber">
        I am on top
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.drunter {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#f00;
}
.drueber {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    background-color:#00f;
}
.drueber:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dooeg5k3/1/)

**Why is this not working?**

When I view the page in Chrome and go about it with the inspector, switch on the :hover state on the "drueber" element, it works as expected. But when I actually hover over the div, nothing happens.

Comment: It´s strange to `hover` st. what is hidden and have `width=0, height=0` (so you can't hover that) :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the `.drueber` has `display:none;` property it can't be hovered. so you need to trigger the hover event on the parent like this :

```
.drunter:hover .drueber {
    display:block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dooeg5k3/2/)**

Comment: Wow! that was a fast one! can't set it as answer yet, but this is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.drunter {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#f00;
}
.drueber {
    display:none;
    background-color:#00f;
}
.drunter:hover .drueber {
    display:block !important;
}
```

i make a little changes in css try this code.

Comment: Thanks waqas, but from what I can tell, this adds nothing to web-tikis answer, right? And I strongly dislike `!important` in my CSS code...